# Swift programming without using mac

Tags: swift

I am new to mobile application development and I have decided to use Swift for iOS development but I don't want to buy a Mac , can I install macOS on another computer and start developing?
Thanks

Comment: This is not really a programming question suited to stack overflow since this is about setting up a "hackintosh". You should delete this question from here and consider posting on a more appropriate site such as [Super User](https://superuser.com) or maybe [Ask Different](https://apple.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: you can try http://www.intoguide.com/install-macos-mojave-virtualbox-windows/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get started with Swift programming this is also possible on Windows. There is an open source [Swift Compiler](https://swiftforwindows.github.io/) for Windows. This is basically useful for learning  Swift and possibly for writing desktop applications, e.g. using [wxSwift](http://www.wxswift.org/), a binding from the portable GUI library wxWidgets to Swift. If you want to program mobile applications with Swift you'll end up with MacOS, but it can possibly be setup as a virtual machine or installed on a regular PC hardware. See also: https://learnappmaking.com/develop-ios-apps-on-windows-pc/

Of course, it is also possible to program [Swift on Ubuntu Linux](https://swift.org/download/) as officially supported by the Swift project. However, Xcode is not available for Linux, so it is basically useful to learn the language